# msTeams static tab configured for live share added automatically to calendar meeting

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js, live-share

We currently have a custom app in teams that has added liveshare functionality which is only accessible in a meeting if the host manually installs the app inside the meeting using a configurable tab.

```
"configurableTabs": [
  {
      "configurationUrl": "$CONFIG_URL/teams/config",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
      "scopes": [
          "groupchat",
          "team"
      ],
      "context": [
        "callingSidePanel",
        "meetingChatTab",
        "meetingDetailsTab",
        "meetingDetailsTab",
        "meetingSidePanel",
        "meetingStage"
      ]
  }
]
```

This will pop the config dialog which will add the tab to the meeting after the user selects save which all works as expected.

We want to change this that the host of the meeting does not have to manually add this and instead the app is automatically added to the meeting with a static tab. I've tried updating the manifest with the following static tab but the app is not appearing in meetings:

```
    "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "Test Meeting",
      "name": "Test Meeting",
      "contentUrl": "$CONFIG_URL/teams/config",
      "websiteUrl": "$CONFIG_URL/teams/config",
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "team",
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "context": [
        "personalTab",
        "channelTab",
        "privateChatTab",
        "meetingChatTab",
        "meetingDetailsTab",
        "meetingSidePanel",
        "meetingStage"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Oh, I see this is actually marked as developer preview only -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-personal-tab?tabs=vs&pivots=node-java-script#extend-static-tabs-to-group-chat-and-meetings